# SQL exceeds the maximum allowed error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I'm pulling data within Data Manager and which is coming via Salesforce so the data type and limits are set in Salesforce which I have no control over. I would like to know how I can limit the the amount of data coming in and inserted into the MS SQL. This is the error:

```
[42000]Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
The size (32000) given to the column 'Description' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
```

And this is my query which pulls the data:

```
SELECT  "Id",
"IsDeleted",
"Name",
"ParentId",
"Type",
"Status",
"StartDate",
"EndDate",
"CurrencyIsoCode",
"ExpectedRevenue",
"BudgetedCost",
"ActualCost",
"Description",
"ExpectedResponse",
"NumberSent",
"IsActive",
"NumberOfLeads",
"NumberOfConvertedLeads",
"NumberOfContacts",
"NumberOfResponses",
"NumberOfOpportunities",
"NumberOfWonOpportunities",
"AmountAllOpportunities",
"AmountWonOpportunities",
"OwnerId",
"CreatedDate",
"CreatedById",
"LastModifiedDate",
"LastModifiedById",
"SystemModstamp",
"LastActivityDate",
"CampaignMemberRecordTypeId",
"Date_of_Event__c",
"Venue__c"
FROM   "SF Schema"."Campaign"
```

Is there anyway to set limit on the "Description" the max is 8000.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to rethink that column before you progress further.

Comment: What is the column size you have set in table schema?

Comment: The schema comes from salesforce so I can not modify varchar to varchar(max) so is there anyway I can make some modification to the SQL query above to limit the site of description to less than 8000?

Comment: Where does this `32000` figure come from? Is this something you have defined somewhere? If so maybe try using `-1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get first 8000 characters using LEFT()

```
SELECT LEFT(Description,8000) AS Description FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

When is this eror happening?

Your error is not comming from your data, but from the DDL of the "SF Schema"."Campaign" table.

How is it possible for that table to have a column of size 32000? Where was it defined?

This little sample code shows how to reproduce your error message.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    dummy nvarchar(32000)
)
```

This produces this output:

Msg 131, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
The size (32000) given to the column 'dummy' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).

Maybe LEFT, as stated in another answer helps you, but I guess that you are going to get the same error, because of the problem being in the definition of the source table.

LEFT on the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177601.aspx